# Matrix inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in H^1(\Omega) $ and $v \in H^1_0(\Omega) $ be 2 vectors

And let $D(u)= \frac{\nabla u + \nabla u^t}{2}$ , and since the gradient of a vector is a matrix then $D(u)$ is a matrix.

How can I prove that:

$\int_{\Omega} div(D(u)).v dx = - \int_{\Omega} D(u):D(v) dx $

We use integration by parts and we know that $v=0$ on the boundary of $\Omega$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your relation is wrong, I expect
$$
\int_\Omega\operatorname{div}(D(u))v_idx
$$
then, taking into account that

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}(u_{i,j}+u_{j,i})_{,j}v_i
&=\left[\frac{1}{2}(u_{i,j}+u_{j,i})v_i\right]_{,j}-\frac{1}{2}(u_{i,j}+u_{j,i})v_{i,j}=\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{2}(u_{i,j}+u_{j,i})v_i\right]_{,j}-\frac{1}{2}(u_{i,j}+u_{j,i})\frac{1}{2}(v_{i,j}+v_{j,i})=
\end{align}
where the last passage is due to the symmetry of the first factor, you arrive at the desired result.

This is just the integration by parts:
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega\operatorname{div}(D(u))v_idx&=\int_\Omega\left[\frac{1}{2}(u_{i,j}+u_{j,i})v_i\right]_{,j}dx-\int_\Omega\frac{1}{2}(u_{i,j}+u_{j,i})\frac{1}{2}(v_{i,j}+v_{j,i})dx\\
&=\int_{\partial\Omega}\left[\frac{1}{2}(u_{i,j}+u_{j,i})v_i\right]n_jda-\int_\Omega D(u):D(v)dx
\end{align}

Comment: And what is the final result?

Comment: @Math1995 I edited my answer

Comment: Why do we have symmetry? I mean why v_ij =v_ji .

Comment: $v_{i,j}$ is not symmetric, but in a product of a symmetric matrix by another matrix, only the symmetric part of the second matrix survives.